# Unable to hit my local API route in Express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, express, ngresource

I have a **server** and **client** folder, inside my client folder I have 2 Angular apps `/website` and `/dashboard`

My current routing setup (just for development) going to `/` will load the website app and views and `/dashboard` loads the dashboard up:

```
//website api ==================================================================
var website = express.Router();
app.use('/', website);
app.use('/', express.static("../client/"));
console.log(__dirname + "../client/");

website.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method, req.url);

    next();
});

website.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var path = 'index.html';
    res.sendfile(path, { 'root': '../client/website/' });
});

//dashboard api ================================================================
var dashboard = express.Router();
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);

dashboard.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method, req.url);

    next();
});

dashboard.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
    var path = 'index.html';
    res.sendfile(path, { 'root': '../client/dashboard/' });
});

// API to add new accounts:
app.post('/api/accounts/', accountsController.create);
```

**In my dashboard app, the accounts controller I have the following $resource call:**

`var Account = $resource('/api/accounts');`

**Which is suppose to hit this API on my server main.js:**

```
// API to add new accounts:
app.post('/api/accounts/', accountsController.create);
```

**However currently getting a 404 on the call**

[image]

'POST http://localhost:9999/api/accounts 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: Perhaps the trailing slash mismatch is the issue? Try `app.post('/api/accounts', accountsController.create);`

Comment: @PeterLyons thanks! Do you want to go ahead and post the answer? Didn't know the trailing / match would be that strict here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the mismatch of trailing slash vs. no trailing slash between your angularjs code and your expressjs code. Try `app.post('/api/accounts', accountsController.create);`.